# Android Fatal Error: Unable to find method makeConcatWithConstants

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have been trying to solve this error and so far I was unable to find the cause. Most threads say that I need to upgrade to JDK 11+. I upgraded the whole project to 17 and it still throws this error. This code is generated by Room code generation, so there is not really anything I can do to easily change it a be done with it.

I am using Android Gradle 8.1.1 which complaints anyway if there is anything below Java 17.

```
AppDatabase_Impl.java:166: error: cannot find symbol

                  + " Found:\n" + _existingLocationData);
                                  ^
  symbol:   method makeConcatWithConstants(Lookup,String,MethodType,String)
  location: interface StringConcatFactory
```

I would really appreciate if anyone would lend a hand with this.
1 error
Fatal Error: Unable to find method makeConcatWithConstants

edit: Added extra context where the issue is reported

```
return new RoomOpenHelper.ValidationResult(false, "location_data(package.data.DatabaseLocation).\n"
              + " Expected:\n" + _infoLocationData + "\n"
              + " Found:\n" + _existingLocationData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this issue has only affected Java code generated by Room I managed to "solve it" by using the new "Kotlin CodeGen" feature of Room which has been introduced in version 2.6 (currently in beta).

> Kotlin code generation(or “Kotlin CodeGen”) can now be enabled in Room
> (4297ec0). To turn on Kotlin CodeGen in Room, add the
> room.generateKotlin option name to your processor options for KSP. For
> more details on how to pass processor options for KSP, see the KSP
> documentation.

I have not managed to find out what was the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Android simply does not implement the `StringConcatFactory` interface. In general Android's support for Java language features seems to be frozen somewhere around Java 8. I definitely would not recommend using any language features or new additions to the class library from Java 9+ in Android applications.

Comment: The problem is I am not directly using it, this is something that was generated by the Room library https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/.

I tried to use even the latest beta version which did not help at all. 

I was forced into the upgrade to Java 17 by the Android Gradle which at the latest version requires it. I even tried to push the min version to API version 34 which is the Android version that natively supports JDK 17, still no luck.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use Android desugaring.

Comment: I am already using             "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:${Versions.desugar}" version 2.0.3